# Convertng labled images (EPS) to interactive web page using ImageMagick, OCR, JavaScript

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick, ocr, tesseract

**Business Insight:** 
We are in education domain and we have a requirement to automate the conversion of [labeled images](http://bit.ly/gH5YY5) (EPS), into interactive exercises 
(using HTML/SVG/JavaScript), used by students.

**Technical Insight:**
Layered EPS files is what we get from the pubishers. The EPS files should be converted into two PNG files: *[1.png]* Which has label texts only *[2.png]* Everything else but label texts.

Then *[1.png]* should be run through some advanced OCR (?) program that should output the label texts along with their positions (X,Y coords) in the image. Then HTML/JavaScript could be used to overlay the label texts over the *[2.png]* along with some interactions like Drag'n'drop using JavaScript.

**Tried so far:**
Manually converted the EPS into PNG and used ImageMagick and Tessaract OCR to get the label text alone.

**Question:**
How far the above requirements of image processing (EPS->PNG+text labels with coords) could be automated and what are the best tools that could be used? Appreciate the help in advance.

**PS:** I'm an UI developer and could handle the HTML/JavaScript part, if just the coords are provided for the labels.